# Upload PDF file in Google sheet using Google apps script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, file-upload

I am trying to upload pdf file to a single cell in google sheet just like we insert image in a google sheet cell. I've searched for quite some time now, but haven't been able to find any solutions to this. I have tried the following code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "File...", functionName: "doGet"});
  ss.addMenu("Attach ...", menuEntries);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("upload attachment into Google Drive");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));

  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeCell", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()));
  formContent.add(app.createHidden("activeSpreadsheet", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.createLabel('saving...');
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B0uw1JCogWHuc29FWFJMWmc3Z1k').createFile(fileBlob);
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');


  var value = 'hyperlink("' + doc.getUrl() + '";"' + doc.getName() + '")'
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.parameter.activeSpreadsheet;
  var activeSheet = e.parameter.activeSheet;
  var activeCell = e.parameter.activeCell;
  var label = app.createLabel('file uploaded successfully');
  app.add(label);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(activeSpreadsheet).getSheetByName(activeSheet).getRange(activeCell).setFormula(value);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Since UiApp has been deprecated so it shows the error "UiApp has been deprecated. Please use HtmlService instead". I have tried the following line to avoid UiApp error but of no use:

```
var app = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput();
```

Is there any workaround that we can get to avoid this error? Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `I am trying to upload pdf file to a single cell in google sheet just like we insert image in a google sheet cell.`. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the PDF file cannot be inserted into the cell. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, if the PDF data has multiple pages, how do you want to do?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you. Yes, if we can insert a pdf file into google sheet and it will be uploaded into a specified folder. The above code did that but since UiApp is no longer available so I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `if we can insert a pdf file into google sheet and it will be uploaded into a specified folder.`. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the PDF file cannot be inserted into the cell. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, if the PDF data has multiple pages, how do you want to do?

Comment: Let's say, there is an add-on, we upload files using that. The general image of pdf will be inserted into a specified cell but that pdf file will be sent to the specified google drive folder. Right now, I am not sure about complication of pdf pages.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand `Right now, I am not sure about complication of pdf pages.`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The general image of pdf will be inserted into a specified cell but that pdf file will be sent to the specified google drive folder.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to try to understand your question. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not able to clarify what you are asking. But a simple explanation would be that we upload a pdf file in the google Sheets cell and that file will be uploaded to the google drive folder (after that we can display the upload success message in that cell). If you run above code in google sheet you will have a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `But a simple explanation would be that we upload a pdf file in the google Sheets cell and that file will be uploaded to the google drive folder`, I think that the PDF data cannot be inserted to the cell. For example, can I ask you about how to insert the PDF data to a cell in your situation? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Ok..let's say I have pdf file in local pc, I would have a google sheet add-on with an option "file upload". I would click on that, it will upload file in the Drive folder which we have specified in script and the active google sheet cell will show the confirmation message.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you wanted to upload a PDF file on the local PC to Google Drive. And you want to put the confirmation message to a cell. You want to achieve this using HTML and Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you where cell you want to put the message to?

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to put the message in currently active cell of the sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before I think of the sample script, I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. You wanted to upload a PDF file on the local PC to Google Drive. And you want to put the confirmation message to a current active cell. You want to achieve this by a sidebar using HTML and Google Apps Script. And, you have no requests for your goal except for this. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes..you are right. Thank you..

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your following comments,

  > I have pdf file in local pc, I would have a google sheet add-on with an option "file upload". I would click on that, it will upload file in the Drive folder which we have specified in script and the active google sheet cell will show the confirmation message.

  > I want to put the message in currently active cell of the sheet
- You wanted to upload a PDF file on the local PC to Google Drive. And you want to put the confirmation message to a current active cell. You want to achieve this by a sidebar using HTML and Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

##### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as the script file and save the script.

```js
const openSidebar = _ => SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"));

function upload(e){
  const message = "sample confirmation message"; // Please set your confirmation message.

  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(message);
}
```

##### HTML&Javascript side: `index.html`

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet as the HTML file and save the script.

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="upload(this.parentNode)" accept=".pdf,application/pdf" />
</form>
<script>
function upload(e){
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = e => google.script.run.upload([[...new Int8Array(e.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
</script>
```

#### Testing:

When you run the function `openSidebar`, the sidebar is opened. And when you select the file from the input tag, the file is uploaded to the root folder of Google Drive, and the confirmation message is put to the active cell.

#### Note:

- In this method, the maximum file size is 50 MB because of the specification of the Google Apps Script side. Please be careful about this.
- **This is a simple sample script for achieving the goal of your question. So please modify this for your actual situation.**

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: Thank you. it works. The pdf is going to root folder of Drive. Can we specify the folder instead of root?

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, it's yes. In that case, please modify `DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e))` to `DriveApp.getFolderById("###folderId###").createFile(Utilities.newBlob(...e))`. By this, the uploaded PDF file is created to the specific folder.